# Python: Correct way to test whether function/method signature has changed

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, integration-testing

I am currently developing an application (`my_app`) that uses logic from another python package (`internal_package`), that is being developed in parallel.

Lets say I use a function `func1` from `internal_package` in my code. In `internal_package`, it is defined like this:

```
def func1(a, b):
    # do something
    ...
```

However, If the function signature of `func1` (i.e. the parameters with which the function is called) changes, lets say to

```
def func1(a, b, c):
    # do something
    ...
```

My code would of course raise an Exception, since I did not pass parameter `c`.

To become aware of that immediately, I want to write a test in pytest. In my understanding, this kind of test is not a unit test, but an integration test.

My approach would be something like this:

```
import inspect
import internal_package

def test_func1_signature():
    expected_signature = ?  # not sure how to correctly provide the expected signature here
    actual_signature = inspect.signature(internal_package.func1)
    
    assert actual_signature == expected_signature
```

I would expect this to be a common issue, but I was not able to find anything related.
What would be the most pythonic way of performing this sort of test?

Comment: Why don't you just call it with 2 arguments?

Comment: you mean like `internal_package.func1(a=1,b=2)` as the sole content of the `test_func1_signature()`-Test function? Without an `assert`- Statement? In that case the Idea would be that if the signature changed, an error raises, otherwise, nothing happens (i.e. the test succeeds). Is that correct?

Comment: Problem: Assume `a`, `b` and `c` are for example dataframes. If I would just call it, I would need valid dataframes `a`, `b` and `c` for the test in order to not raise any errors. However, I solely want to test whether the parameters of `func1` are called `a` and `b` (and if given `c`) and in this case do not have any default values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, I ended up using `getfullargspec` from the inbuilt `inspect` library. In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfullargspec) it says:

> Get the names and default values of a Python function’s parameters. A named tuple is returned:
> `FullArgSpec(args, varargs, varkw, defaults, kwonlyargs, kwonlydefaults, annotations)`

As I am interested in in the `args` part, I retrieve them from `func1` as follows:

```
inspect.getfullargspec(func1)[0]
```

Which then returns `['a', 'b']`. I can then write a simple test in pytest like this:

```
import pytest
import inspect

def test_func1_signature:
    expected_signature = ['a', 'b']  # I specify what i expect

    actual_signature = inspect.getfullargspec(func1)[0]

    assert actual_signature == expected_signature
```

If anyone knows a better/more pythonic/more correct way, please let me know.